# how to use one database in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

```
public class project
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int UserprojectId { get; set;  }
    public int? SponserId { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EstimateTime { get; set; }

}
public class projectDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<project> projects { get; set; }
}
```

and this model

```
public class sponser
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateRegister { get; set; }
    public String CompanyPhone { get; set; }
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set;  }
    public bool EmailConfirmation { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; } 
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }

}
public class sponserDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<sponser> sponsers { get; set; }
}
```

and in my web confige file 
i add this this name

```
<add name="SponseringDB"
  connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=sponseringDB;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
/>
```

When run this and create some Record for me it made two database first `sponseringDb` and second is `projectDb` I want to use one database.

Need suggestions on achieving this.

Comment: alignment corrected. formatting improved and added line for clarifying question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two classes inherit by DbContext and that is the reason why 2 database are created, if you want to have just one databe ie: projectDB

change you projectDB class to

```
    public class projectDB : DbContext
    {

   public projectDB () : base("projectDBConnectionString") //<- name of your connection string
        {
        }
        public DbSet<project> projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<sponser> sponsers { get; set; }
    }
```

and in your web config add connection string named 'projectDBConnectionString' ie:

```
<add name="projectDBConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=sponseringDB;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
/>
```

and now your can rid off connection string 'SponseringDB' from web.config and delete class 'sponserDB'

Hope that will help